# Using Future to return after a series of async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am writing a JavaScript (node.js) function that makes several exec() calls (asynchronously) and I need to use Future to return after all of them are completed.

What I have is:

```
run: function(command, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
    var child = exec(command, options, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      // calculate `answer`

      if (answer == "wrong") callback(answer);
    });
  }
},
```

So, if `answer` is "wrong", then I can easily call the callback and that's it. However, if all the answers aren't "wrong" (in other words, if all the `exec` have `answer=="correct"`) then I have no idea of how to return such value.

I know I can use `Future` (from `npm`) for this. However, I can't really see how to use it in this case (where I don't have just 1 async call, but multiple async calls).

Comment: After finished your loop invoke the `callback()` function, it seems that all answers are crrect if loop would iterate completely.

Comment: The problem with that is that sometimes I'll callback after the loop and the last case hasn't been tested yet. Then I get a double callback (one saying Accepted and one saying Wrong).

Comment: To invoke the callback function we should know about exact events, one is `wrong answer`, other is  I can't understand, if all correct answer or  if some time correct answer, what exactly other event would be, please clearify it.

Comment: At least 1 Wrong should call back Wrong and all Correct should call back Correct.

Comment: Do you want to run `exec` in parallel (all at the same time), or sequentially (one after another)?

Comment: Sequentially (parallel would be awesome, but possibly very hard to implement), I believe I need each exec() call to wait for the previous one to finish to start so I don't get `Text file busy` issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#timesn-callback) library

```
async.times(testCases.length, function(n, next){
    var child = exec(command, options, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      // calculate `answer`

      var data = {answer : answer};
      if (answer == "wrong") {
        next({err: answer}, data);
      }
      else {
        next(null, data);
      }
    });
}, callback(err, data) {
    // you can also check for err
  // we now have an array of data[testCases.length]
});
```

Comment: I am getting `Text file busy` because I don't think this is waiting for an execution to finish to start another one, asynchronously. https://github.com/davidgomes/evaluator.js/blob/master/evaluator.js

Comment: Right. You were trying to overwrite the same file same time.
Try [async.timesSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#timesseriesn-callback) instead.

Didn't fully understand your requirement until I looked at the code on github. I see you are using objects in testCases array in your callback.  You could also look into using [eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback).

Comment: `async.timesSeries` worked very well, even if I still get a `Text file busy` now and then (rarely).

Comment: My bet is that the operating system hasn't fully released the file handle before the next iteration of `timesSeries` starts up.  Try wrapping your `next` call in a `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(function() { next(null, data); }, 100);`... that's probably overkill, if you're only rarely getting the problem now, you could probably cut it down to an even smaller timeout.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to check for the number of commands completed -

```
var totalCompleted = 0;
var done = false;
for (var i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
    var child = exec(command, options, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      // calculate `answer`
      totalCompleted++;
      if (answer == "wrong" && !done) {
         done = true;
         return callback(answer);
      }
      if(totalCompleted === testCases.length && !done) {
         callback('right');
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: That seems to work, except I need a sleep.sleep(1); in each loop iteration.

Comment: just encompass exec call within process.nextTick

Comment: Like this? https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/67b478bf33c7887b9715 I mostly get a `Text file busy` but other times I actually get Accepted.

Comment: actually that doesn't matter. the exec call anyways is async and hence will run in next tick or some other event loop.